# Changing the CSS class of a master page component

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, menuitem, menubar

I have a project developed using ASP.net.
I have placed the menu bar in the master page and I need to change the active menu bar item according to the loaded page.
Here is my code.

Site.Master

```
 <div class="menu-bg">
     <ul class="menu wrapper">
         <li><a href="Default.aspx" id="menu1">Home page</a></li>
         <li><a href="About.aspx" id="menu2">Our Company</a></li>
         <li><a href="Services.aspx" id="menu3">Our services</a></li>
         <li><a href="Projects.aspx" id="menu4">Our projects</a></li>
         <li><a href="Careers.aspx" id="menu5">Careers</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

For example, if I load Default.aspx page the Menu bar item "Home Page" should get a different color.
Is there any possible way to do this?
Please help me.

Comment: you might need to write a page specific css which will target particular a tag. As you are differentiating them based on ID, it will be easier.

Comment: Can u explain the strategy?

Comment: you will need to include style on the particular page itself. i.e. on default.aspx define #menu1 style and so on.

Comment: But, can I access the master page component directly?

Comment: atleast you can upvote my comment in that case :)

Comment: Oh sorry... I thought we can upvote only answers.. :)